# How to use like query with Mongo DB C# driver

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

We have checked google for this and find some solutions but those are not fully working.

Ex. `filter = filter & builder.Regex(val.Name, string.Format("/{0}/", value));`

We have used Regex for this but it is case sensitive filter. Example I want to search text "A Brand new Project" but when I enter "New" as search text then I can find this record but when I enter "new" keyword, I don't get that record.

Is there any way to use like query with MongoDB.

Comment: There should be an `ignorecase` flag

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Yes there is ignore case flag is available. But now problem is that is only limited to alpha-bate search. Solution is filter = filter & builder.Regex(val.Name,new BsonRegularExpression(value, "i"));. But if my record is "ABC (new content)"  and if I try with "(new content)" then it will not work.

Comment: @jitendra: I think I have seen something like this. Try `filter = filter & builder.Regex(val.Name,new BsonRegularExpression(Regex.Escape(value), "i"));` (mind adding *System.Text.RegularExpressions* namespace)